# Declaring variable globally show output but does not show when declared locally on a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I declare an input globally prints the output. However, when I declare an input locally on a function it gives error message that the input is not defined:

```py
def fizzbizz(num):
    num = input("Enter Num:")

    if (num % 3 == 0) and (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Fizzbizz"
    if(num % 3 == 0):
        return "Fizz"
    if (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Bizz"

print(fizzbizz(int(num)))
```

Comment: If you `input` `num`inside your function, why would you pass it an argument? You should rather put the input outside of your function.

Comment: On the line `print(fizzbizz(int(num)))` you're passing in `num`, but that doesn't exist and the `num` value assigned in the function can't make its way out (it won't be assigned to `num` globally) - just remove the `num` from that call and remove the function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of the code, get input outside the function

Global

```
num = input("Enter Num:")
def fizzbizz(num):
    if (num % 3 == 0) and (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Fizzbizz"
    if(num % 3 == 0):
        return "Fizz"
    if (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Bizz"

print(fizzbizz(int(num)))
```

Local

```
def fizzbizz():
    num = int(input("Enter Num:"))
    if (num % 3 == 0) and (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Fizzbizz"
    if(num % 3 == 0):
        return "Fizz"
    if (num % 5 == 0):
        return "Bizz"

print(fizzbizz())
```